# How to Wake ES8266 from deep sleep on Dev board NodeMCU

Tags: sleep, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

Basically, my project uses a force-sensing resistor to detect occupancy on the chair. The ESP8266 WiFi would wake from the sleep mode and send an update to the server. If there is no occupancy, the ESP8266 goes back to sleep.
My project uses Wiolink, a dev board that uses a ESP8266 WiFi chip. Hence, it is quite impossible to connect GPIO 16 to RST to wake up ( or reset ) the device.
Deep sleep is predefined at a set amount of time using this function ESP.deepsleep(). Is it possible to wake up with an external interrupt such as the force sensing resistor?

```
String apiKey = ""; //     const char* ssid = ""; // wifi username const
char* password = ""; // wifi password


    void setup()  // Defines the initial condition of the hardware board.
    {   
      Serial.begin(115200);   delay(10);
    }

    void loop() // Defines the loop condition of the hardware board. {
    sensorReading = analogRead(A0);

    if(sensorReading >= 150) // Condition when someone is sitting;

     {    
       //Wake ESP8266    
       //perform server update  
     }

    if(sensorReading <=149) // Condition for no one sitting; 

     {
       Serial.println("Going into deep sleep");
       ESP.deepSleep(); //    
     }
```

Comment: No, it is is not possible to wake up ESP using any external event or external interrupt because in ESP.deepSleep(0)(in case your deep sleep is infinite) only real time clock(rtc) is on.

Comment: @vaibhavsharma Would it work with a light sleep mode? According to the datasheet, the CPU would be pending during light sleep mode. What ways could the CPU be used may I ask?